# CSRF protection, error if turned on, error if turned off?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-security

I am working on a web application and running into a problem when I submit my form it shows a CSRF protection error, This would'nt be a problem as I do not need it in this form(contains no sensitive data and I have implemented that only users with some privilige(role) can acces this page).

My problem is this when I use  `'csrf_protection' => false,` in my FormType options I get the following error: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "myroute"

I wouldn't mind CSRF protection being on but then it shows this ugly error in my twig:

> CSRF token invalid, try to send the form aigan

Yes i know the above block isnt exatcly what it says but I translated it from my native language.

Does anyone know a quick fix for this?

**Controller Function**

```
    /**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="score_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, Duel $duel, DuelRepository $duelRepository): Response
{

    $form = $this->createForm(ScoreType::class, $duel);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('score_edit');
    }

    return $this->render('score/edit.html.twig', [
        'duels' => $duelRepository->findAll(),
        'duel' => $duel,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

**Form Type**

```
    class ScoreType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('puntenP1', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Punten',
                'attr' => array('style' => 'height: 25px;')
            ])
            ->add('eerstenP1', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Eersten',
                'attr' => array('style' => 'height: 25px;')
            ])
            ->add('puntenP2', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Punten',
                'attr' => array('style' => 'height: 25px;')
            ])
            ->add('eerstenP2', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Eersten',
                'attr' => array('style' => 'height: 25px;')
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Duel::class,
            //csrf protection not needed for "scores"
            //'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Twig file**

```
   {{ form_start(form) }}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p><b>Partuur 1</b></p>
        {{ duel.team1 }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        {{ form_row(form.puntenP1) }}
        <p>Huidig: {{ duel.puntenP1 }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        {{ form_row(form.eerstenP1) }}
       <p>Huidig: {{ duel.eerstenP1 }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p><b>Partuur 2</b></p>
        {{ duel.team2 }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        {{ form_row(form.puntenP2) }}
        <p>Huidig: {{ duel.puntenP2 }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        {{ form_row(form.eerstenP2) }}
        <p>Huidig: {{ duel.eerstenP2 }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 10px">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Always include enough code to understand what's happening in practice (like the controller and form declaration here, and perhaps a Twig template). The first says you're generating a route without an `id` component, which doesn't seem like CSRF, the second you may not be including the (Twig?) `{{ csrf_token('form') }}` call in the form. It's been awhile, so I don't recall exactly. Plus, CSRF works with logged-in users since it uses their session to submit the request, so disabling CSRF when someone is logged in is nonsensical, and the sensitivity of the data is also not the always the point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I updated my post

Comment: Try `{{ csrf_token('form') }}` between `{{ form_widget(form) }}` and `{{ form_end(form) }}` and don't disable it. You can look in the browser source as well to see if the token's input field is included.

Comment: Adding that does provide the csrf token so I do not understand why it would say it is invalid

Comment: I assume you are using the actual Symfony framework?  Just for grins try editing config/packages/framework.yaml and explicitly setting csrf_protection true.  Make sure you refresh afterwords and manually check to verify the form's csrf token matches the one in the session.  It all should work out of the box but maybe you tweaked something while trouble shooting.  By the way, csrf protection is not for protecting sensitive data but rather to avoid folks from posting from unknown locations.  You probably don't really want scores being posted from unknown sources.

Comment: What is the point of redirecting back to the same exact method? It looks to me that if you did provide the id there you would be caught in an endless loop, just remove that line and allow it to return the response.

Comment: I might add that using {{ form_widget(form) }} is a bit puzzling in this case.  I would have expected {{ form_rest(form) }} but maybe you have your reasons.  @ArleighHix It is perfectly normal to redirect after a post.  It verifies that your data was indeed properly posted and stops the browser from complaining about reposting the same data.  They probably will need to include the id but that will be obvious once they reach that line.

Comment: @ArleighHix The reason for that is in the symfony doc it is best practise to use one function to either check if the form is valid and if so submit it or otherwise render the form in the twig

Comment: @Cerad Hmm.. I tried your suggestion and find this pretty weird when I add the csrf token to the twig it renders it but in the error the csrf token value is empty " "

Comment: You do understand that your 'missing id' error is unrelated to csrf?  Go back and turn csrf off then follow the answer to add the missing id to your redirect.  You should get a clean posting and redirect.  Then take a step back and maybe create a different form completely and figure out why your csrf config is broken.  Deal with one problem at a time.

Comment: @Cerad you are completly right, I need to put my feet back on the ground thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code that causes the problem:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('score_edit');
```

You redirect the user to this route without parameters, but the route has required parameters:

```
@Route("/{id}/edit", name="score_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
```

You have to add the required parameter to your route:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('score_edit', [
    'id' => $duel->getId(),
]);
```

Comment: It's strange to see a question with a specifically CSRF-related title solved with a routing-specific answer. Do you know how to solve the CSRF problem too?